# Can I use 1 mm² wire for 24 VDC / 15 A load?

Tags: current, wire, 24v

I am currently using 1 mm<sup>2</sup> copper wire for a my application of driving a 360 watt motor, haven't caused any problems for me yet. The total wire length is around 3 meters. a voltage drop of 0.5 V ~ 1 V is acceptable with 5°C rise in cable temperature. Should I change the cable to 2.5 mm<sup>2</sup> or is the 1 mm<sup>2</sup> safe?

Comment: You should compute the temp rise using AWG tables

Comment: @Tony, why not compute the temp rise using *metric* tables? d:^)

Comment: We would have used Chemical Rubber Tables

Comment: It sounds like you already have everything set up. If so, I would suggest that you simply measure the voltage drop and temperature rise. You can put a thermocouple on the wire. Record temperature before you start and when you are done. Subtract. That is your temperature rise. Or, if you accurately measure the current and voltage drop across the wire, then you can calculate the wire resistance change from cold to hot. And then you can use that change to calculate the temperature rise in the wire (because copper resistance increases as it gets hotter).

Comment: Just did a test run, with 12A load. The 1sqmm does elevate in temperature a bit say a 5 to 10'C (for a 5min continuous load). The load motor runs intermittent and does not run for more than 2min per session or so. a session lasts for half an hour. Th voltage is drop measured is 0.8V after 5min of continuous load.

Comment: Does that meet your requirements?

Comment: Yes it does. But, I've decided to go with 2.5sqmm just to avoid risks. Thank you very much, the answers were really useful and will help me decide right in future.

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be no because the voltage drop will be 0.77V (not 0.5V) and at 15A, it's 11.5W you are losing heating your wire.
Even if it may not heat too much, and you won't risk a fire or burning yourself (yet be very careful), it's still a lot of energy wasted. Even with 2.5, you still lose 4.7W.
Therefore I would recommand a 4mm wire to be within acceptable range.

Working with low voltage and high current, you must always choose the thickest wires as possible. You can also use two or more wires in parallel if the gauge of a single wire is too large. If there is only one small screw terminal allowing only one small gauge wire, you can also connect a very short wire to a bus terminal for larger gauge wires and connect one or several larger wires for the longer distance. Yet, it would make no sens to build a power supply without enough big terminal for the current it's able to provide. Often they offer two screw terminals on which you can attach up to 4 x 2.5mm wire (one on each side of each screw).
Always use single strand (monolithic) wire.

Addendum: For short duration, less than one minute with several minutes in between when it can cool down, a smaller gauge may be acceptable. But you must make sure there is no risk of the motor running longer and that you or somebody aware of that are the only persons operating the device.

Answer (score 0):

That's a little light (equivalent to [AWG 18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge)). I think 2 or 2.5mm^2 would be better.

To get an exact answer you have to take the insulation rating and maximum ambient, any bundling and the maximum altitude into account, as well as voltage drop. Voltage drop will increase somewhat as the wire heats.

Answer (score -1):

The generally accepted figure for 1 mm<sup>2</sup> wire is 10 A, but that's for wires run with others. As heating goes as \$I^2R\$, you can see 15 A generates a bit more than twice what is generally considered acceptable.

If you're happy with the voltage drop, then 15 A in 1 mm<sup>2</sup> wire is just about usable as long as it's single wires in an open environment. So go ahead if this is a hobby application for you. Do not load wire this thin like this if the equipment is going to leave your use (it's OK to risk overheating yourself, not OK to endanger others).

I generally remember a room temperature figure of 17 mΩ for 1 m of 1 mm<sup>2</sup> wire, convenient use-sized units. Your 3 m of wire is therefore around 50 mΩ, or 0.75 V total drop, a little more if hot. That's not a large fraction of 24 V, but would be much less with 2.5 mm<sup>2</sup> wire.

Whereas it's easy to do the sums for resistance and voltage drop, it's much less practical to estimate temperature rises, as they so depend on the convection environment. I could as easily compute the power dissipated in the wire as I did the voltage drop, but it's meaningless for temperature rise without the cooling. Run the motor. See how hot your wires get *configured how they will always be run*. So don't test them in the open, and then later put them in conduit. Perhaps the most accurate way to measure the temperature of a copper wire is to measure its resistance. At this low resistance, using an ordinary DMM directly will not work. Far better to measure the current through and the voltage across it while the motor current is flowing. Copper has a thermal coefficient of resistance of about 0.4% per °C, or 10% increase for 25 °C, so it's sensitive enough to measure.

Comment: I'm making an effort to write figures with units consistently and correctly, so space between figures and unit, and units upper or lower case depending on whether they are based on somebody's name. To me the spaces look ugly. I hope you appreciate the effort!

Comment: You're doing well! You can go further: SE supports `<sup>...</sup>` and `<sub>...</sub>` for super and subscript and HTML entities such as `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space - useful if you want to ensure the numbers and units stay on the same line), SI standard is that units named after a person have their symbols capitalised but are lowercase when spelled out, except for 'Celcius' for some reason. The space between the numbers and units is also part of the standard and reads much better. ("19figs" or "19 figs"?). You only failed on "Ohms".

Comment: @Transistor where's the degree symbol for use with C, or do I just use unicode?

Comment: ```&deg;C``` the degree symbol + C ... was about to wonder if you meant per coulomb :^p

Comment: I've tried the & before and they 'hadn't worked', it was the ; that I'd missed!

Comment: 15A is a bit on the high side for safety, the load usually runs at 12A max and runs only intermittently. This is for a hydraulic table where the motor runs till the user operates it and sets the position. Once the position is set the user doesn't change/operate much. The load doesn't run for more than 2 minutes continuously.

Comment: Where I live, in India the regulations states a maximum current of 6A per mm.square of Cu conductor. Extrapolating that, the generally accepted value around anywhere in the world will never be 10A/mm2.

Comment: @Transistor Celsius is not actually the measurement unit. The actual unit is degree Celsius , and the d in degree is lowercase. Compare it to kelvin, which currently has no degree in front of it (but had it historically), and is also written lowercase.

Comment: Kelvin should be capital as it is a unit and it is also named after an induvidual